# Unable to validate realtime when using the rules method in laravel with livewire 3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to perform a real-time validation on a form using livewire 3. According to the livewire documentation, when attempting to use run-time syntaxes such as Rule::password(), you should define a rule method instead of using the #Rule. When you want to validated on realtime, you should use either wire:model.live or wire:model.blur. However, I'm unable to get the validation to run in realtime. The validation only runs when I click on the register button.

In my Register livewire component, I've defined the rules method like this

```php
public function rules() {
    return [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:2'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'lowercase', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:'.User::class],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
    ];
}
```

Then in my register method, I have made sure I called $this->validate() as shown below.

```php
public function register(): void
{
    $validated = $this->validate();

    $validated['password'] = Hash::make($validated['password']);

    event(new Registered($user = User::create($validated)));

    auth()->login($user);

    $this->redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME, navigate: true);
}
```

Also in my view, I ensure that wire:model.blur is added like this

```html
<x-text-input wire:model.blur="name" id="name" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="name" required autofocus autocomplete="name" />
<x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('name')" class="mt-2" />
```

What I'm I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Livewire 3 the rules provided in *function rule()* are not automatically applied in real time, they are only applied when *$this->validate()* is called
To get around this you can use the *#[Rule]* attribute for validation, on each property.
Otherwise you can use the *updated()* method to force validation using the validations defined in *rules()*:

```php
public function updated($prop) {
   $this->validateOnly($prop);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this from official documentation:

> Real-time validation
> Real-time validation is the term used for when you validate a user's input as > they fill out a form rather than waiting for the form submission.

```
wire:model.live or wire:model.blur

<form wire:submit="save">
    <input type="text" wire:model.blur="title">
 
    <!-- -->
</form>
```